# Better way to check and update line in file VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, filereader

I am trying to check a bunch of files that should have a leading | delimiter but sometimes don't.  If the first line doesn't have the |, the rest of the file won't, if it does have it, then the rest of the file will.

So I'm checking the first line which works and enters the update logic, which advances to the next row once I read the line in.  So I added a writer.Write before I go into the Do While loop and it works, but it seems like there would be a better way of doing this.

Here is my code:

```
            Dim fileList As FileInfo() = dirList.GetFiles

        For Each fiName In fileList
            sFullName = fiName.FullName
            sFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fiName.ToString)
            sDir = fiName.DirectoryName
            Dim reader As New StreamReader(sFullName)
            Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()

            If Not line.StartsWith("|") Then

                Dim sNewFullName As String = sDir + "\" + sFileName + "_Temp.txt"
                Dim writer As New StreamWriter(sNewFullName)
                Dim sLine As String

                sLine = "|" + line + System.Environment.NewLine
                writer.Write(sLine)

                Do While reader.Peek() <> -1
                    sLine = "|" + reader.ReadLine() + System.Environment.NewLine
                    writer.Write(sLine)
                Loop

                writer.Close()
                reader.Close()
                File.Delete(sFullName)
                File.Move(sNewFullName, sFullName)

            End If
            reader.Close()
        Next fiName
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated, Thank you in advance...

Comment: If your code works and you just need a better way, then the Code Review Stack Exchange would be a better location for this question.

Answer (score 0):

This way works just fine. There are several other ways to do it, but it's a matter of opinion on which is better, based on simplicity, portability, performance, maintainability, etc.

For example, you could read the entire file into a string using `file.readalltext`, then change all VBCRLF (or whether the line end character is) to VBCRLF & "|", then write it all out with file.writealltext.

If it was me, and if it works, I'd leave it unless I just wanted to learn some other methods. Some would argue for hours for another method that is better, but it may be more productive to move on to the next project.